# implementing a method that returns true if all argument is in the range

Tags: java, recursion, refactoring

i want to implement method `s` such as :

> given 2 int values, returns true if either of them is in the range
>   10..20 inclusive.

simple answer is:

```
public boolean s(int a, int b) {    
    return (a > 9 && a < 21) ||  (b > 9 && b < 21);
}
```

but how implement without duplicated use of pattern `(x > 9 && x < 21)` and without new method? has a recursive solution?

Comment: But what's wrong with the existing solution? It is the correct way of doing this.

Comment: It's not duplicated, as you're comparing different variables. This is the simplest and correct way.

Comment: Except this will return true if either of the arguments is in the range, not if both are. For both to be in the range you need to replace `||` with `&&`.

Comment: The title and question body are contradictory ("all" vs. "either of them")

Comment: @طاهر do you want to check for all argument in the range?

Comment: we have just two argument

Comment: @طاهر What the issue with my solution that accepts any number of int arguments.

Comment: you change the method signature that may come from an interface or super class...

Comment: @Braj another way is to put then into a array at first line of method

Comment: @طاهر yes you are right but that's what `varargs` does it for me. I don't need to do anything.

Comment: @طاهر OK I will update it in my post as per your suggestion.

Comment: @Braj thanks to you attention to this question. but it changes the signature that isn't a good-practice in refactoring...

Comment: My preferred solution would be the one that the owner deleted.

Comment: @طاهر OK I have updated it in my post. It was not clear from your question that you can't change the method signature or you are doing refactoring but now its clear to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a recursive solution, then I would suggest this:

```
public static boolean s(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        return (a > 9 && a < 21);
    }
    return (a > 9 && a < 21) || s(b, 0);
}
```

However, this is far less readable than your original solution.

---

**EDIT** Per @طاهر, a more concise version

```
public static boolean s(int a, int b) {
    boolean r = (a > 9 && a < 21); 
    return b == 0 ? r : r || s(b, 0); 
}
```

Comment: you will get an error when you do : b || s(b,0). b is an integer!

Comment: @طاهر Don't change answer made by other especialy if you add wrong code. Someone may downvote the answer and it's the original author you will get its point reputation down.

Comment: @user230137 That was an edit someone else made to my answer. The original answer stands.

Comment: I'm awre of that I edited your answer after look at my comment after

Answer (score 3):

Try this code using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) and pass any number of int values to test.

> implementing a method that returns true if any argument is in the range

As per your question - returns true if either of them is in the range 10..20 inclusive.

```
public boolean s(int... a) {
    for (int i : a) {
        if (i > 9 && i < 21) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

--EDIT--

> implementing a method that returns true if all argument is in the range

```
public static boolean s(int... a) {
    for (int i : a) {
        if (i < 10 || i > 20) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (a.length > 0);
}
```

--EDIT--

put a check **if needed** in the beginning of the method but I never suggest you to use it.

```
    if (a.length != 2) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("It accepts only two arguments");
    }
```

--EDIT--

as per your requirement if you can't change the method signature that may come from an interface or super class.

```
public boolean s(int a, int b) {

    int[] array = new int[] { a, b };

    for (int i : array) {
        if (i > 9 && i < 21) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But he say that the function take only 2 arguments!

Comment: No problem check for the length and through an exception if length is not 2

Comment: @user230137 I think we have to code for generic solutions that fits for all possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Either add a new method, or let this "code duplication" live.
It's one (half) of line of code, it's not really duplicated, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this but it's not the best solution :

```
public static boolean s(int a, int b) {
    int n = a * b;
    if (a == 0)
        n = b;
    if(b == 0)
        n = a;
    for (int i = 10; i < 21; i++)
        if( n % i == 0 )
            return true;
    return false;
}
```